# Is a question really "Only One Question"?

Tags: support

In a [comment on my answer to this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/217108?noredirect=1), a commenter said...

"Naturally people disagree about these kind of things, but if we credibly read the OP as being only one question (**as the site demands**)..."

What is the definition of this concept of "credibly read the OP as being only one question" that the site demands and where is the requirement documented on the site?

Does what the site demands conflict with [this site guidance](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that says

> Any answer that fully addresses at least part of the question is helpful and can get the asker going in the right direction.

The site guidance seems to imply that

1. It is alright for a question to have multiple parts, and,
2. That an answer is considered useful if it addresses at least part of the question.

Answer (score 4):

The question asked in that post, the only credible question that would be a good, well formed question here on Space.SE, is the headline one:

"When does the space shuttle stop its gravity turn?"

This has been explained to you by members of the community who have been here for years, and know very well how the site works - in fact they were part of the core group who have set direction and guidance for this site.

To answer specific points you raise here:

1. No, we do not want multiple questions in a post, that is not what the guidance implies at all. There are cases where closely related questions may be in a post, but the guidance allows for answers which may not fully address the question at first, although can hopefully be improved over time.
2. Not necessarily - it's still got to be an answer that meets quality requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ironically, I asked too many questions. The main one I wanted to get answered was the "question interpretation" guidance, "*credibly read the OP as being only one question*" as the site demands. Where is this requirement documented on the site?

Comment: @phil1008 in [the closed questions explanation](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) under Needs More Focus: "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." I see the same language most frequently in the close-voting box